# When is the body of a Promise constructor callback executed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Suppose I have the following code constructing a `Promise`:

```
function doSomethingAsynchronous() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const result = doSomeWork();

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(result);
   }), 100);
  });
}
```

At which point in time is `doSomeWork()` called? Is it immediately after or as the `Promise` is constructed? If not, is there something additional I need to do explicitly to make sure the callback is run?

Comment: [ECMAScript, 25.4.3.1 `Promise(executor)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor) -> Step 9

Comment: It doesn't matter: if you need to enforce order of operations, do so explicitly. Different implementations will handle promises with slight differences in behavior (bluebird vs native map, for example).

Comment: @guest271314 I'm writing some tests and need to mock a function that returns a Promise. I want the Promises the mock returns to resolve immediately so that the tests run successfully, so I just wanted to double-check that there wasn't some kind of magic I had to invoke to get them to run.

Comment: That, and I want to understand how Promises work under the hood.

Comment: @Kevin Why are you adding this question with *"If not"* ? Did you see my answer ? It is **guaranteed** the executor is always immediately executed even before the Promise constructor returns. There's no "implementation details" here, it's specified.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, yep, I saw your answer (and I'm likely to accept it). I added the third question to add some more context for why I was asking the question for future readers, but I don't need any more clarification myself.

Comment: This may help explain things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031051/resolve-order-of-promises-within-promises/42043784#42043784.  It covers a slightly more complicated situation (a promise within a promise), but definitely covers what is going on here, including what happens when a promise resolves before the `.then()` handlers are attached.

Comment: Please don't close this question as a duplicate of one which only has bad answers. And *no*, this isn't implementation dependent but specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Promise constructor callback executed asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29963129/1048572)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It is called synchronously, yes, by specification.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#Parameters):

> The `executor` is called synchronously (as soon as the `Promise` is constructed) with the `resolveFunc` and `rejectFunc` functions as arguments.

This is defined in the ECMAScript specification (of course, it's harder to read...) [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-executor) (Step 9 as of this edit, showing that the executor is called synchronously):

> 9. Let completion be Completion(**Call(executor, undefined, « resolvingFunctions.[[Resolve]], resolvingFunctions.[[Reject]] »)**).

*(my emphasis)*

This guarantee may be important, for example when you're preparing several promises you then pass to `all` or `race`, or when your executors have synchronous side effects.

Comment: _Immediately_ is confusing. The executor is really called **synchronously** by the Promise constructor.

Comment: It seems that MDN and the ES spec doesn't say that anymore, but I think you can still assume it runs sync since the steps 1-11 mentions return a promise, which you do get back synchronously. It doesn't mention running it async or queueing it somewhere like how [PerformPromiseThen](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) says "Append fulfillReaction as the last element of the...".

Comment: One addition: it will be executed instantly (synchronously), but `then()` will call its callback in the next tick (asynchronously).

Comment: yes, Executive function block is executed synchronously. But the resolve and reject function call back is depended on then() and catch() calls. So then() is calling resolve and reject funs call back asynchronously, i.e making them wait in micro task queue and executing them when the class stack is empty. so when then() is calling the resolve and rreject asynsly what is the use of again making the executive func block async by wrapping it in the setTimeout() ?

Comment: @dosentmatter The spec never will say "it is synchronous" or "it is asynchronous". It simply prescribes the steps that the algorithm to interpret javascript code needs to run. The callback to `new Promise` simply is called before the constructor returns the new object. You don't have to "*assume*" anything. The abstraction used to describe the steps may have changed since ES6, but the behaviour is still the same, and this will not change.

Comment: @KondavetiCharan "*the resolve and reject function call back is depended on then() and catch() calls*" - no. "*then() is calling resolve and reject funs*" - no.

Comment: @Paleo I came here from Google trying to figure out whether it's *genuinely* guaranteed to be called synchronously, or if it's only *merely* immediately, which could be at the bottom of the event loop. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude As I understand the documentation and the specification, it is guaranteed. I just edited for adding clarity.

Answer (score 28):

You can see below the body is executed immediately just by putting synchronous code in the body rather than asynchronous:

```js
function doSomethingAsynchronous() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("a");
    resolve("promise result");
  });
}
doSomethingAsynchronous();
console.log("b");
```

The result shows the promise body is executed immediately (before 'b' is printed).

The result of the Promise is retained, to be released to a 'then' call for example:

```js
function doSomethingAsynchronous() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("a");
    resolve("promise result");
  });
}

doSomethingAsynchronous().then(function(pr) {
  console.log("c:" + pr);
});
console.log("b");
```

Result:

```
a
b
c:promise result
```

The same deals with asynchronous code in the body except for the indeterminate delay before the promise is fulfilled and 'then' can be called (point `c`). So `a` and `b` would be printed as soon as `doSomethingAsynchronous()` returns but `c` appears only when the promise is fulfilled ('resolve' is called).

What looks odd on the surface once the call to `then` is added, is that `b` is printed before `c` even when everything is synchronous.

Surely `a` would print, then `c` and finally `b`?

The reason why `a`, `b`, and `c` are printed in that order is that no matter whether the code in the body is `async` or `sync`, the `then` method is always called asynchronously by the `Promise`.

In my mind, I imagine the `then` method being invoked by something like `setTimeout(()=>{then(pr)},0)` in the `Promise` once `resolve` is called. I.e. the current execution path must be complete before the function passed to `then` will be executed.

Not obvious from the `Promise` specification why it does this.

My guess is it ensures consistent behavior regarding when `then` is called (always after the current execution thread finishes) which is presumably to allow multiple `Promises` to be stacked/chained together before kicking off all the `then` calls in succession.

Comment: interesting addition to the a/b/c example - adding `await` before the `doSomethingAsynchronous().then()` call makes it write a/b/c, so when Promises are awaited, it behaves pretty much as expected

Answer (score 19):

Yes, when you construct a `Promise` the first parameter gets executed immediately.

In general, you wouldn't really use a `promise` in the way you did, as with your current implementation, it would still be synchronous.

You would rather implement it with a timeout, or call the resolve function as part of an ajax callback

```
function doSomethingAsynchronous() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      const result = doSomeWork();
      resolve(result);
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

The `setTimeout` method would then call the function at the next possible moment the event queue is free

Answer (score 6):

From the [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor)

> The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise
> implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is
> called before the Promise constructor even returns the created object)

Consider the following code:

```js
let asyncTaskCompleted = true

const executorFunction = (resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("This line will be printed as soon as we declare the promise");
  if (asyncTaskCompleted) {
    resolve("Pass resolved Value here");
  } else {
    reject("Pass reject reason here");
  }

}

const myPromise = new Promise(executorFunction)
```

When we execute the above code, `executorFunction` will be called automatically as soon as we declare the `Promise`, without us having to explicitly invoke it.