# Assigning a function to a variable without invoking

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a file, myClass.js which has a class with function in it.

```
class MyClass {
    func1(param1, param2) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(param1+param2);
        })
    }
} 

const myObj = new MyClass();

module.exports = myObj;
```

Then I call that function from another file and feed it through Promise.all.

```
const myObj = require('myClass.js') 
let funcPromise1 = myObj.func1(1, 2);
let funcPromise2 = myObj.func1(2, 3);
let funcPromise3 = myObj.func1(3, 4);

Promise.all([funcPromise1, funcPromise2, funcPromise3])
    .then(values=> {
        console.log(values)
    });
```

The problem is that the func1 gets invoked when I assign it to the variable.
I could wrap it in another Promise, but that seems like an anti-pattern.

```
let funcPromise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { myObj.func1(1, 2).then(sum=>{resolve(sum)}).catch(err=>{reject(err)});
```

I could just place the function in the promise all, but it starts to get hard to follow.

How can I not invoke this function immediately?

Comment: Why don't you want you functions to be invoked? You need to promises they return. When *should* they be invoked if not before passing them to `Promise.all()`?

Comment: I want them to be invoked in the promise.all, so if one of them fail, I can catch it then. The actual code it transactional, so I would rollback on failure.

Comment: Calling the fns within Promise.all() or assigning to variables then passing to Promise.all have the same effect.

Comment: @MattKuhns It doesn't matter when the function is called, as long as it returns a promise then `Promise.all` will catch any failures.

Comment: Btw, you should not use `class` syntax when you want to export a singleton instance. Just use an ordinary object literal.

Answer (score 0):

[Promises are executed immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118995/1715579)

However, you can simply wrap the promises in another function that you can explicitly invoke only when you want them to execute. In the following example, your `myObj.func1` gets called early, but the actual promises are delayed until after a button is clicked.

```js
class MyClass {
  func1(param1, param2) {
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('executed', param1, param2);
      resolve(param1 + param2);
    })
  }
}

const myObj = new MyClass();
let funcPromise1 = myObj.func1(1, 2);
let funcPromise2 = myObj.func1(2, 3);
let funcPromise3 = myObj.func1(3, 4);

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  Promise.all([funcPromise1(), funcPromise2(), funcPromise3()])
    .then(values => {
      console.log(values)
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Go</button>
```

A more complex approach is to wrap each `func1` promise with another promise that will invoke `func1` only when some other promise is resolved. This is effectively the same as the first solution (both are just a way to delay the call to `new Promise` inside `func1`), but it could be preferred in your situation because `func1` doesn't change and the call to `Promise.all` doesn't change, only the initialization of the `funcPromiseN` variables.

```js
class MyClass {
  func1(param1, param2) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('executed', param1, param2);
      resolve(param1 + param2);
    })
  }
}

const clicked = new Promise(res => {
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', () => res());
});
const delayed = (p, fn, ...args) => p.then(() => fn(...args));

const myObj = new MyClass();
let funcPromise1 = delayed(clicked, myObj.func1, 1, 2);
let funcPromise2 = delayed(clicked, myObj.func1, 2, 3);
let funcPromise3 = delayed(clicked, myObj.func1, 3, 4);


clicked
  .then(() => Promise.all([funcPromise1, funcPromise2, funcPromise3]))
  .then(values => {
    console.log(values)
  });
```

```html
<button id="btn">Go</button>
```