# Is the promise resolved, when I push promise array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I want to push promise to an array. Then I want to resolve it using `Promise.all()`. But I'm not sure, is promise work when i push to array?

For example:

```js
const productIds= [1,2,3,4,5,6] // example
const promises = [];
productIds.map(productId => promises.push(ProductDataAccess.updateProductStock(store,productId,incQuery)));
```

If I don't Promise.all(), will db process occur? Or does the db process occur when I make Promise.all().

```js
const productIds= [1,2,3,4,5,6] // example
const promises = [];
productIds.map(productId => promises.push(ProductDataAccess.updateProductStock(store,productId,incQuery)));
Pormise.all(promises);
```

Comment: if you dont use Promise.all(promises), promise in the promises array will not be executed

Comment: Promise executes just as you create it. Method `Promise.all` simply helps you wait till all promises have finished executing, provided they all resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't Promise.all(), will db process occur?

It depends. The general answer is **yes**. But be aware that this is not always true.

Normally, functions that return a Promise schedules an asynchronous process when you call them. So the asynchronous process **will happen** regardless of you waiting for them.

However, there are some functions that don't really return a promise. They return a promise-like object. And sometimes (not always) they don't start the asynchronous process unless you call `.then()`. And database libraries that use fluent/chainable functions do this. This is a common design pattern in database libraries:

```
// knex example:

let x = knex('my_table').select(['id','some_info']); // will not trigger db query
console.log(x); // knex object - not a Promise!

x = x.where('id', 0); // still no db query
console.log(x); // still not a Promise!

x = x.then(result => console.log(result)); // TRIGGERS DB QUERY!
console.log(x); // Yay! A Promise!
```

Lots of database libraries do this in order to implement a fluent/chaining style API that is transparent to the user. They detect the end of query construction by the `.then()` function being called.

Now, I don't know what database library you are using but **if you are affected by this** then to trigger the database query process you will need to call `then` either directly or indirectly:

- call `.then()` yourself
- pass the object to `Promise.all()` which internally calls `.then()`
- `await` the result in an `async` function which internally calls `.then()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, promises run when they are created, not when they are awaited upon (be it with `Promise.all()` or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

You will [start the execution of the promises from the moment each promise is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118900/when-is-the-body-of-a-promise-executed/42118995#42118995) (regardless of the usage of `Promise.all`), but not wait for them.

If this block of code is in an `async` function, you can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the promises in this way (and also, you can simply use `map`, without `push`, to build the array of promises you need):

```
const productIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const promises = productIds.map((productId) => ProductDataAccess.updateProductStock(store,productId,incQuery));

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Those points are valid, but the actual question `If I don't Promise.all(), will db process occur? Or does the db process occur when I make Promise.all().`  is only indirectly "answered" by `otherwise, you will start the execution of them - from the moment each promise is created -, but not wait for them`

Comment: @t.niese Yes, good point! Rearranged my answer a bit upon your feedback. Thanks!