# why we cannot refer own self in promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm just experimenting and came across this:

```
    var d = 7;
    var p1 = new Promise((a, b) => { 
        console.log(p1);
        console.log(d);
        a('whatever');
    });
```

I'm just curious about what's going on here. The fact that I'm really sure this gonna work, but doesnt, means there's a gap in my understanding. could anyone explain why `p1` is not reachable from inside `a`, but `d` is?
workaround is easy, but I just want to understand this one.

Thanks.

Comment: You're logging `p1` before it is assigned. That's really it.

Comment: Assignment happens from right to left. The Promise constructor executes its executor immediately. Does this help?

Comment: [When is the body of a Promise executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118900)

Comment: dang, how can I overlook this simple fact...yeah you guys are right...guess this is what happens when you're too focused on API and lose sight of the basic of basics...thanks all

Comment: Related: [Javascript: Access Promise object from within function passed to Promise constructor](/q/48289911/4642212).

Comment: You can confirm the order of things with the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-executor). Also, consider `const p1 = Promise.resolve().then(() => { console.log(p1); return "whatever"; });`, which requires one pass through the job queue, before calling the `then` callback.