# Understanding JS event loop and render cycles in browser

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, event-loop

After watching these talks on the JS event loop and rendering in browsers ([What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and [Web browser event loop, setTimeout, micro tasks, requestAnimationFrame...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)), I was experimenting on what types of delays will block rendering in a browser.

I'm testing these 4 approaches:

- Synchronous long task (`delayLoop` function in the demo): This behaves as I understand from the talks. A long task takes up the call stack and so the browser is not able to push renders into the stack. This causes the UI to freeze up till the long task is completed.
- Promise resolve callback running a long task (`delayPromise` function in the demo): This behaves similarly as well. This time the microtask (promise's callback) takes up the call stack with a long task, which defers the render tasks till it is complete.
- New Promise callback running a long task before resolve (`delayPromiseReturn` function in the demo): This behaves similarly as well. Although what I don't understand is why the logs of `func` are not printed immediately. I had expected `func` to complete and have the promise callback run in the stack post that.
- setTimeout callback running a long task (`delayTimeout` function in the demo): This behaviour I **don't** understand. I had expected the UI to freeze up after 5 seconds as the callback task would occupy the call stack and block the render tasks. Instead the animation completes normally, and the callback task also completes normally in the background (console logs get printed), without any effect on the rendering.

```js
function delayLoop() {
    console.log('starting for loop')
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {}
  console.log('ending for loop')
}

function delayPromise() {
    Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('starting promise')
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {}
    console.log('ending promise')
  })
}

function delayPromiseReturn() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log('starting await')
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {}
    console.log('ending await')
    
    resolve()
  })
}

function delayTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('starting timeout')
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {}
    console.log('ending timeout')
  }, 5000)
}

function func() {
    console.log('starting delay func')
    
  document.querySelector('.anim').classList.add('start')
    /* delayLoop() */
  /* delayPromise() */
  /* delayPromiseReturn() */
  
  delayTimeout()
  
  console.log('ending delay func')
}
```

```css
.anim {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

.start {
  animation: rotation 1s linear 10;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
<div class="anim"></div>
```

Any explanations for the Promise return (`delayPromiseReturn`) and setTimeout (`delayTimeout`) behaviours ? Please correct me if anything is wrong in my understanding of the other points.

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**, not (or not only) as a jsFiddle.

Comment: There really isn't any difference between delayPromise and delayPromiseReturn

Comment: **Warning**: Clicking the button in the demo will hang your browser (ot at least the tab) until the "processing" is finished.

Comment: `delayPromiseReturn` is more or less the same as `delayLoop`, since [`Promise` constructor callbacks are executed synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118900/1048572)

Comment: I highly recommend [_JavaScript Visualized: Event Loop_](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-event-loop-3dif) for a general explanation of the event loop.

Comment: @Bergi So when something like axios makes a request and returns a Promise that we can run `then` on, I'm assuming the request is made as part of the Promise callback inside axios ? Is that synchronous then ?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Read the article. From what I understand it does pretty much re-iterate what was mentioned in the first talk I've linked. Even in the article's example they mention running the setTimeout callback as part of the call stack, which is similar to the normal for loop example and so it should block the rendering, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Bergi Came across this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#never_blocking. Seems like XHR requests are non-blocking in general ?

Comment: @DevanshSharma Yes, the request is started and the xhr completion event handlers are attached synchronously from within the `new Promise` callback. Yes, XHR requests are asynchronous (non-blocking), otherwise it wouldn't make sense to wrap them in a promise. Using promises does not make anything asynchronous ("run it in the background"), it only simplifies handling result from tasks that are already inherently asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi, this clears up some misconceptions I did not know I had :) Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi, if I could pick your brain some more :) I came across this article: https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-event-loop-call-stack/#web-apis. Is it right to assume all inherently async APIs are added by browsers/node to core JS/v8 engine ? And so they take care of running them in the "background", so that core JS thread need not get blocked by it ? But then again why would the JS thread worry about rendering...
Any place I can find a list of what browsers/node add extra to JS (like setTimeout, fs and other things) ?

Comment: @DevanshSharma "*Is it right to assume all inherently async APIs are added by browsers/node to core JS/v8 engine?*" - yes, precisely. And on top of those you can build your own APIs and libraries, that make things easier to use and wrap multiple things in a single method, which then will be asynchronous as well - but only because deep down it uses the network, timers, ui events or similar.

Comment: "*why would the JS thread worry about rendering...*" - it doesn't, necessarily, except that rendering is pointless to do while js code is still running and modifying the DOM. So rendering simply waits until all JS has finished - that's where the connection to the event loop is. (In theory a browser could regularly make snapshots of the DOM and continuously render those to the screen, but it doesn't happen in practice and also won't be implemented because nobody expects a browser to behave that way)

Comment: "*Any place I can find a list of what browsers/node add extra to JS*" - it's in the platform documentation. For nodejs, see http://nodejs.org/api/, for browsers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API (due to popularity, some "web" APIs like `fetch` are also becoming available in node). Other JS platforms may provide their own builtins, e.g. on a microcontroller you'd have functions that control the I/O pins.

Comment: @Bergi, Is it safe to assume that the JS event loop is not the process that does the rendering, but the rendering thread implemented in the browser?

Comment: @NapoleonBonaparte Not sure I understand the distinction between "*the process that does the rendering*" and "*the rendering thread*". I don't think you should make assumptions about how the browser implements this.

Comment: @Bergi, I was just wonderring if the render is done by some other process in the browser instead of the event loop.

Comment: @NapoleonBonaparte Does it make a difference? I think there's both kinds of implementations in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have some concepts

- Synchronous Task
- Asynchronous Task
- Global Execution Context
- Callback Queue
- Microtasks Queue

Secondly, I want to classify them according to the 5 concepts above:

1. `func()`, `delayLoop()` is synchronous task and it belongs to the GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT: if you call it explicitly like action of click event. it always execute first.
2. Asynchronous task is excuted after a task that runs in the "background" finished, non-blocking, doesn't wait for an asynchronous task to finish its workd.

   Therefore,the only callback function inside  `delayTimeount()` is asynchronous task and it's not relevant to Promise. So, it belong to CALLBACK QUEUE.
3. Promise is an object that is used as a placeholder for the future result of a asynchronous operation. There are 2 states: pending and settled (fulfilled or rejected).

   So, the callback function in `.then()` of `delayPromise()` and it belongs to MICROTASKS QUEUE.
4. `delayPromiseReturn()`, it return a promise, when it's called, the only callback function inside is belongs to MICROTASK QUEUE.

Thirdly, one important thing, asynchronous task does not happen in JS engine, EVENT LOOP manages them at run time.

In queue is FIFO (first in, first out), and in JS, GLOBAL CONTEXT first order, MICROTASKS QUEUE is second and the last one is CALLBACK QUEUE.

After reading all the things above, I give some tests:

1. call `func()` with `delayLoop`

   ```js
   function func() {
     console.log("starting  func");
     delayLoop();
     console.log("ending func");
   }
   ```

   the code inside of `func()` will run in sequence,
   because it is pushed to call
   stack (sequence) - first in,
   first out. From GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT, `func()` and `delayLoop()` will be pushed to CALLBACK QUEUE, and execute in sequence

   that's why log to console like this:

   ```
   starting delay func
   starting for loop
   ending for loop
   ending delay func
   ```
2. Call `func()` with `delayLoop()`, `delayPromise()`: remember every code in `func()` is sequential.

   ```js
   function func() {
     console.log("starting func");
     delayLoop();
     delayPromise();
     console.log("ending func");
   }
   ```

   from GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT, `func()`, `delayLoop()`, `delayPromise()` will be pushed to CALLBACK QUEUE, they was executed in sequence. However, the callback function in `.then()` of delayPromise will be pushed to MICROTASKS QUEUE and it is scheduled to run later when callstack empty

   that's the reason why `delayPromise()` start after `delayLoop()` finish.

   ```
   starting delay func
   starting for loop
   ending for loop
   ending delay func
   starting promise
   ending promise
   ```
3. Call `func()` with `delayLoop()`, `delayPromise()`, `delayPromiseReturn()`:

   ```js
   function func() {
     console.log("starting func");
     delayLoop();
     delayPromise();
     delayPromiseReturn();
     console.log("ending func");
   }
   ```

   the callback function inside of `delayPromiseReturn()` will be pushed to MICROTASKS QUEUE and it is scheduled to run later when callstack empty. That's the reason why `delayPromiseReturn()` start after `delayLoop()` finish.

   ```
   starting delay func
   starting for loop
   ending for loop
   starting await
   ending await
   ending delay func
   starting promise
   ending promis
   ```
4. Call `func()` with `delayLoop()`, `delayPromise()`, `delayPromiseReturn()`, `delayTimeout()`:

   ```js
   function func() {
     console.log("starting func");
     delayLoop();
     delayPromise();
     delayPromiseReturn();
     delayTimeout();
     console.log("ending func");
   }
   ```

   the only callback function inside of `setTimeout()` in `delayTimeout()` will be pushed to CALLBACK QUEUE and it has lowest priority, after all, microtasks queue empty, callback queue empty, it will run.

   that's why, it start after `delayPromise()` finish.

   ```
   starting delay func
   starting for loop
   ending for loop
   starting await
   ending await
   ending delay func
   starting promise
   ending promis
   starting timeout
   ending timeout
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detail! It makes sense what you mention, but my main question was on how all these delays interact with the rendering process. As I had mentioned in the question, only the timeout approach did not block rendering, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @DevanshSharma, I think you can resolve your problem after understanding the concepts that I mentioned. About block rendering, I'm sorry, I can not help you.

Comment: "*you can google to read more about them*" is not a good answer. Also, your post does not really answer the OPs core question.

Comment: "*please correct me if I am wrong*" - yes, this is wrong on multiple accounts. Or at least so sloppy/inprecise, I don't even know where to start. The most obvious thing is "*it belongs to the GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT: it runs first if it called.*" or "*When the GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT empty*" - that's just plain wrong. And statements like "*`delayTimeount()` is asynchronous task*" or "*`delayPromise()` with fulfilled state will be handled with then()*" need to clearly distinguish between the part of the code that runs now (on the call stack) and the part that is scheduled to run later.

Comment: thanks for your explaination. Firstly, Because there are too many conceprs, I can write all down in awser and almost of them is avaiable like docs.  Second, yeah, I got what you said. I said "it belongs to the GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT: it runs first if it called." becasue every program need a point to start, if I dont press click, there is nothing in console.

Comment: I'm updating the answer to distingguish betweent the part of code runs (callstack) and the part that is scheduled to run later.

Comment: @Bergi, if my updated version is still wrong, please let me know, i will delele my answer

Comment: Thanks for making it more specific. Now it's easier to point out what exactly is wrong :-)

Comment: "*it belongs to the GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT: if you call it explicitly like action of click event. it always execute first.*" - I wouldn't call that a global execution context. There is no distinction between a timeout handler or a click handler from the view of the event loop. If anything, the global execution context is the `<script>` that defines (and attaches) the event handler functions, but in a browser, there's not actually a single point where execution starts since there might be multiple scripts in a page.

Comment: "*the part code inside of delayTimeount() is asynchronous task*" - no. It's the function that is passed to `setTimeout` that is an asynchronous callback, not all the code in `delayTimeout`. Similarly, it's not the "*Promise inside of delayPromise() […] [that] belongs to MICROTASKS QUEUE*" but only the callback function passed to `.then()`. Also I get hung up on "*from GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT, func(), delayLoop(), delayPromise() will be pushed to CALLBACK QUEUE, they was executed in sequence.*", since those functions are just called and not pushed to any queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255510/discussion-between-manh-do-and-bergi).