# How to promisify a callback-based function while preserving the returned value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I was provided with this API:

```
function doSomeWork(callbacks : {
    success ?: (result : SuccessCallbackResult) => void,
    fail ?: (result : FailCallbackResult) => void,
    complete ?: (result : CompleteCallbackResult) => void
}) : Task
```

With a simple wrapper, I got a function that returns a `Promise`:

```
function doSomeWorkAsync() : Promise<SuccessCallbackResult> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const callbacks = {
            success: resolve,
            fail: reject,
        };

        doSomeWork(callbacks);
    });
}
```

But I lose the `Task` returned by `doSomeWork` in this way.

Can I wrap the API in some way that I can get both a `Promise` and a `Task`? Something like this:

```
function doSomeWorkAsync() : [Promise<SuccessCallbackResult>, Task] {
    // implementation
}
```

And I need the `Task` returned synchronously because I might need it to `.abort()` itself.

Comment: Return and array with the promise and the task.

Comment: @jabaa `doSomeWork()` is in the closure passed to the `Promise` constructor. How can I pass its return value to the outer function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that defines/declares everything you're using, so that we can test it out in our own IDEs.  Right now our IDEs will just complain about `SuccessCallbackResult`, etc, and `Task`, and lack of `doSomeWork()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I wrap the API in some way that I can get both a `Promise` and a `Task`?

Yes, the `new Promise` callback is executed synchronously:

```
function doSomeWorkAsync(): [Promise<SuccessCallbackResult>, Task] {
    let task;
    const promise = new Promise((success, fail) => {
        task = doSomeWork({ success, fail });
    });
    return [promise, task];
}
```

(TypeScript may require a `task as Task` assertion if it doesn't know that `task` has been assigned before it is used)

Comment: When I first came up with this approach and didn't regard it as a final solution, the real question that stood in my way was [When is the body of a Promise constructor callback executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118995/1688023). Since the closure is executed *before* the constructed `Promise` is returned, preparing a variable to be assigned should be a valid way. Thanks for making it clear!