# how promise is resolving before the settimeout delays in async await javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, settimeout

I am learning about async await in javascript. What I understood is if there is an async function then inside is if there is a promise prefixed with await. then upon the function execution the function execution will be suspended untill the promise is resolved.

So what I tried doing is, I created 2 promises in this method which resolves after 5 and 10 secs respectively. and in between I had added a console.log for hello world

```js
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('p1 fulfilled'), 5000));

let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('p2 fulfilled'), 10000));

async function test() {
  const res1 = await p1;
  console.log(res1);
  console.log('hello world');
  const res2 = await p2;
  console.log(res2);
}
test();
```

Now if we go by understanding that I shared above then upon execution of test method first
P1 resolved will be printed and untill it resolves further things should not get executed. and this is happening that only after P1 resolves then only hello world is getting printed.

bt doubt arises when the promise 2 is getting resolved after 5 sec of promise 1 resolved.

I am confused in like if it actually suspended function execution then 2nd promise should have taken 10sec after 1st promise execution. and if it executes in parallel means then js has reached to this line even before promise 1 resolves if that's the case then why hello world not printed

Thanks in advance

Comment: `await` doesn't "start" a promise. `let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('p2 fulfilled'), 10000));` does. So you first wait for `p1` which takes 5 seconds *and also 5 seconds tick off `p2`*.

Comment: but await prevents the code execution after it unitl it resolves so how it reached to P2 or if execution didn't blocked then y hello world not printed

Comment: Again, when the promise was created, the time is already ticking to its resolution. That's 10 seconds regardless of the `await`. The keyword `await` doesn't block timers, only the lines of code after the `await`. And only in the same function. Other code can and does execute.

Comment: See [When is the body of a Promise constructor callback executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118900)

Comment: ohk got it. You are a Gem .