# Order for async operations in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Initially I have question about the order of number in code

```js
(function() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 0);
    Promise.resolve(true).then(() => console.log(2));
})();
```

And for myself I've explained it like `setTimeout` uses 4ms in fact instead of 0.

But code works in same manner with `setImmediate`

```js
(function() {
    setImmediate(() => console.log(1), 0);
    Promise.resolve(true).then(() => console.log(2));
})();
```

Man who asked the question said that the reason is the fact, that in v8 Promises is not part of webapis and run inside loops.

Maybe there are any other explanations? Or links to find more details?

If I use Loupe for visualization I see the same

[Loupe visualization](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=KGZ1bmN0aW9uKCkgewogICAgc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiBjMSgpeyBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygxKSB9LCAwKTsKICAgIFByb21pc2UucmVzb2x2ZSh0cnVlKS50aGVuKGZ1bmN0aW9uIGMyKCkgeyBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygyKTsgfSk7Cn0pKCk7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D) - I'm looking for explanation

Comment: There is no such function `setImmediate` maybe you've meant `setInterval`?

Comment: Have you read through the extensive answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises)?

Comment: @Krusader [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#globals_setimmediate_callback_args) is defined in Node.js.

Comment: OK now when you've added node.js tag it makes sense.

Comment: @Krusader tag is there

Comment: @Pointy if you're about the fact that Promises are async - I know it. Either I miss something in the answer?

Comment: @Krusader setImmediate works in IE for example, not only node.js

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk it's asynchronous, but the relationship between Promise callbacks and timer callbacks is not specified and is left up to the runtime. It would be unwise to rely on any particular behavior.