# Variable becomes undefined inside promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm working on an Ionic 3 app which uses [Ionic Native Google Maps plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/).
I'm trying to use [node pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) with the Google Maps instance to create a marker pool.

My problem is that inside the new Promise in the createPool function, this.map is undefined, even though it has been created by the loadMap() function.
I read [this awesome post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises/36877743#36877743) about promises but I can't figure out how that applies to my case. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready()
      .then(_ => {
        return this.loadMap()
      })
      .then(_ => {
        this.markerpool = this.createPool();
        this.markerpool.on('factoryCreateError', err => console.log(err));
      })
} 


createPool() {
    var factory = {
      create: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.map.addMarker({
            icon: 'assets/icon/sun.png',
            visible: false
          })
            .then(marker => {
              // icon anchor set to the center of the icon
              marker.setIconAnchor(42, 37);
              resolve(marker);
            })
        })
      },
      destroy: function (marker: Marker) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          marker.remove();
          resolve();
        })
      }
    }
    var opts = {
      max: 60, // maximum size of the pool
      min: 20 // minimum size of the pool
    }
    return GenericPool.createPool(factory, opts);
  }

loadMap() {
    this.mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 40.9221968,
          lng: 14.7907662
        },
        zoom: maxzoom,
        tilt: 30
      },
      preferences: {
        zoom: {
          minZoom: minzoom,
          maxZoom: maxzoom
        }
      }
    };

    this.map = this.googleMaps.create(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
    this.zoomLevel = this.getZoomLevel(maxzoom);
    return this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY);
  }
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside new Promise is not the same as the outer `this` in which the map is loaded. You can declare a member variable inside `factory` which is assigned to the outer `this`, or to the outer map and use that inside the new Promise instead.

```
var factory = {
    outerthis: this, //or outermap:this.map
    create: ...
       ...
       this.outerthis.map.addMarker(... //or access this.outermap.addMarker directly
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'm so used to the fat arrow functions that I didn't notice it!

Answer (score 0):

If you had used an arrow function instead of `create: function () {`, the `this` inside the value would have been the object that `createPool` is called on (which has the `map` property), not the `factory`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `var` with `let`.
`let` keeps the variable scope of outside of function.
Also you need to use `()=>{}` instead of `function()`

```
let factory = {
  create: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.map.addMarker({
        icon: 'assets/icon/sun.png',
        visible: false
      })
      .then(marker => {
        // icon anchor set to the center of the icon
        marker.setIconAnchor(42, 37);
        resolve(marker);
      })
    })
  },
  destroy: (marker: Marker) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      marker.remove();
      resolve();
    })
  }
}
let opts = {
  max: 60, // maximum size of the pool
  min: 20 // minimum size of the pool
}
```