# Why promise.race returns none when one of parameters reject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I created 3 promise, p1, p3 resolve while p2 rejects.

code:

```
            let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(42);
            });
            let p2 = Promise.reject(43);

            let p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(44);
            });
            let p4 = Promise.race([p1, p2, p3]);

            p4.catch((value) => {
                console.log(value); 
            });
```

Base on code, p4 is supposed to return 43, because p3 runs faster than p1 and p2. When I run in node, it returns none.
How to explain this situation in Promise.race?

Note: Please run this code in console then answer it.
It doesn't return anything in my local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the order of execution in javascript promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises)

Comment: @ibowankenobi , I just read that post, there is no code for Promise.race

Comment: The order cannot be relied. You cannot say, p3 or even p1 will run faster than the other. You have 4 expressions evaluated at the same tick of event loop, there is a separate microtask queue for promises and you cannot say which one will run faster.

Comment: Np, good luck with your project.

Comment: By now you probably figured out that you're passing resolved or rejected promises and `Promise.race` will return the first resolved or rejected it finds so `let p4 = Promise.race([p2,p1, p3]);` will log something in `catch`. If you need a function that will return first promise that resolves or rejects if all promises reject you can try [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L368-L416)

Answer (score 2):

As you've written them in your example, thee promises `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` all settle at the same time*.

From the [docs of `Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

> If the iterable contains one or more non-promise value and/or an
>   already resolved/rejected promise, then Promise.race will resolve to
>   the first of these values found in the iterable.

While those promises aren't already settled when given to `race`, since they all settle at the same time, `race` will use the result of the first one in the list. In this case, that's `p1`.

So:

```
p4.then(console.log) // Prints 42
```

and you can verify that by noting that if you change the order of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` in the array you give to `race`, you'll always see the result of the first one.

```js
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(42);
});

let p2 = Promise.reject(43);

let p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(44);
});

let p4 = Promise.race([p1, p2, p3]);
let p5 = Promise.race([p2, p1, p3]);
let p6 = Promise.race([p3, p2, p1]);

p4.then(r => console.log("p4", r), r => console.log("p4", r));
p5.then(r => console.log("p5", r), r => console.log("p5", r));
p6.then(r => console.log("p6", r), r => console.log("p6", r));
```

Comment: Hi, the truth is it return nothing, you can run it in terminal. It cannot return anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"it cannot return anything"*. If you mean you don't see any logs, it's because your `p4.catch( ... )` code will never execute since the promise does not reject, but resolves with `42`.

Comment: I see, p2 is already rejected so p4's result is ignored, so console.log(value) in p4 returns nothing, right?

Comment: no p4's "result" is a promise that resolves to 42 - your `console.log` only executes if p4 rejects