# What happens first: setTimeout 0 or await Promise.resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm seeing this behavior in Node and Chrome:

```
setTimeout(()=>{ console.log('timeout') }, 0)
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{ console.log('promise') })
console.log('sync')

// output order:
// sync
// promise
// timeout
```

My question is, is this consistent behavior? I.e, according to spec, does a `then` or `await` on a memoized/already resolved promise always fire before `setTimeout(fn, 0)`?

I want to use this in something like the following, returning one thing if I have a memoized result in my promise and another if not:

```
// somewhere during object initialization
this.resultingPromise = expensiveAsyncFunction()

// in a method called frequently
Promise.race([
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('default'), 0)),
    this.resultingPromise
])
```

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that logic suggests it will always work that way.  I don't know the inner workings of either mechanism, but if you set up a timer, create a resolved promise and then output to the console I'd expect to see what you show.  The console.log works immediately, the timer is then created and set to execute the callback, and the resolved promise is executed.  Then, the timer callback is executed because that would be the next step - the timer countdown hits zero.  That sounds sensible to me, and I trust JS to be sensible.

Comment: This article by Jake Archibald might help clarify this behavior: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877743/5378743 summary point 2 the you can't rely on an order.

Comment: Thanks @ArnelleBalane, saw now you had posted roughly the same thing before kirill.buga did in their answer below. I think I should read up on micro-/macrotasks to understand this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Promise.resolve will schedule a microtask while setTimeout schedule a macrotask. And the microtasks will run before running the next macrotask.

More information about event loop in general: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

More technical details about events loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: This is a bit enlighting, will check out the videos. Found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933985/1555158 suggesting this concept of micro-/macrotasks might be in the WHATWG standard. Is the WHATWG standard also part of es6 and the likes? Or am I getting this wrong, the guy only refers to WHATWG to point out that a `task queue` is in that standard

Comment: Okay. going to accept this answer. From the @ArnelleBalane link above (https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/#what-are-some-browsers-doing-differently) it seems ECMAScript defines a notion of "jobs" rather than being explicit about what's actually microtasks and macrotasks. So even though implementations have this consistent behavior, I can't find anything stating that it _must_ always have the above execution order

Answer (score 1):

so you have 2 async waiting States, but notice that one of them is constant and one is changing (variable). The timeout is set in an XML variable aside while the promise could took forever. If I understood your question quite well, when you have something you rely on take too long and something too short, unless you have a constant applied on one of them like the timeout, then one might end up running shorter unexpectedly (!) Be prepared for that and instead use monolithic structure from code security reasons and not performance.

Comment: Sorry, I saw my mistake there. Edited the question to have a function run in `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that one will be before the other. If you want to guarantee the order of execution - use Promises.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding `Promise` has a higher priority in the call stack than `setTimeout`, and of course synchronous code block will be the first to be executed. In that case, yes the observed behaviour above (in the order of synchronous code block, promise.resolve, and setTimeout 0) should be consistent.