# Does the scheduling race really exist during this multiple promise.then() condition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, event-loop

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises) question recently since I'm trying to clarify my concept about Javascript event loop and microtasks. Although the top answer in that thread got more than 100 upvotes, I still have some doubts with some of the descriptions in that.

Here's the code from that thread:

```
1     Promise.resolve('A').then(function (a) {
2         console.log(2, a);
3         return 'B';
4     }).then(function (a) {
5         Promise.resolve('C').then(function (a) {
6             console.log(7, a);
7         }).then(function (a) {
8             console.log(8, a);
9         });
10        console.log(3, a);
11        return a;
12    }).then(function (a) {
13        Promise.resolve('D').then(function (a) {
14            console.log(9, a);
15        }).then(function (a) {
16            console.log(10, a);
17        });
18        console.log(4, a);
19    }).then(function (a) {
20        console.log(5, a);
21    });
22   
23    console.log(1);
24    
25    setTimeout(function () {
26        console.log(6)
27    }, 0);
```

The author said the following comment.

> Anyway, in your case, it's a scheduling race and the engine you are running decides to run the inner .then() handler that's defined on line 5 next and thus you see the 7 "C" specified on line 6. It then returns nothing so the resolved value of this promise becomes undefined.

In my understanding of the microtask queue, it's the implementation of the job queue of ECMAScript in the browser environments. From the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#microtask-queue), each event loop has only one microtask queue. As a result, if this code runs in a browser environment, while it goes to line 5, the .then() on line 5 is pushed to the microtask queue since the Promise fulfilled immediately, and on line 12, because the previous Promise is also fulfilled and returned, the .then() on line 12 is pushed to the microtask queue. **Therefore, I don't see any scheduling race here since all the promises are fulfilled immediately and we only have one microtask queue.**

Moreover, even we run this code outside any environment, such as browsers or Node.js, from the [ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues), we should at least have two kinds of job queues that are PromiseJobs queue and ScriptJobs queue. Anyway, it sounds like the implementation of JavaScript engine also groups the Job Queues by types. **Hence, I think we will also have only one PromiseJob queue (or I'm wrong?), and still have no scheduling race here.**

The same question also came up when I saw the description about line 13 and line 19.

> Again, all synchronous code is done so it goes back to the scheduler again and it decides to run the .then() handler defined on line 13. That runs and you get the output 9 "D" and then it goes back to the scheduler again.

Could someone tell me are there really scheduling races here or not?

Comment: Not sure what you are willing to understand, nor what is meant by "scheduling race". There is no race condition here, all these promises can be converted to `queueMicrotask` calls which are all queuing the microtask synchronously. So there is a clear order of execution. https://jsfiddle.net/zp8qkw10/

Comment: Just checked the answer there, you're right not trusting it.

Comment: @Kaiido I totally agree with you since I also don't know what "scheduling race" means there. Now I could ensure that there's no race condition here. Just wonder I was wrong or not because so many people upvote that answer.

Comment: Well it's an old thread, things weren't really as clear as they are now and it's hard to prove that something is not random, and many people just like what seems to be true, moreover when it's surrounded by tons of wordings.

Comment: Nice comment, thanks

Comment: For what it's worth I added a new answer there.