# A better way to render this function component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, render, use-state

The goal of the below code is to pull data from a firebase realtime database into an array called popularMovies. (The amount of data in the realtime database is 1000.) Then a random index is picked from that array and the movie data at that index is displayed on the page. When the user clicks the liked button, that movie data is stored in a firestore document under the user's id, and another random index is chosen to display a new movie.

The below code mostly works, but I've noticed that the console.log("run!") executes 1000 times (the size of the data being read) both when the page loads and when the liked button is clicked. I was hoping to understand why that is the case given that it is outside the forEach loop that reads the data.

Additionally, when the button is clicked once, all the data updates but the display doesn't reflect the changes. However, clicking the button again does update the data again along with the display (as I would expect to have happened the first time). And this continues with the button only updating the display after every other push. I would also like to know what might be causing that bug.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';

function RateMovies() {

    const popularMoviesRef = firebase.database().ref("/popular_movies");
    const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = React.useState([]);
    var [render, setRender] = React.useState(1);

    console.log("run!");

    useEffect(() => {
        
        popularMoviesRef.once("value", function(snapshot){

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var data = childSnapshot.val();

                setPopularMovies(currMovies => [...currMovies, { 
                    key: key, 
                    movieTitle: data.movie_title, 
                    moviePoster: data.movie_poster, 
                    movieYear: data.movie_year,
                    movieGenre: data.movie_genre, 
                    movieRating: data.imdb_rating
                }])
            });
        });
    }, [render]);

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
    var movie = popularMovies[index];

    const auth = firebase.auth();
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var user_id = auth.currentUser.uid;

    function likedMovie() {

        db.collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
            "Rated.liked": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                key: movie.key, 
                movieTitle: movie.movieTitle, 
                moviePoster: movie.moviePoster, 
                movieYear: movie.movieYear,
                movieGenre: movie.movieGenre, 
                movieRating: movie.movieRating,
             }),
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log("Successfully updated!");
            setRender(render++);
        });

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
        movie = popularMovies[index];
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <p>Rate Movies Here</p>
            <div> {movie?.movieTitle} </div>
            <div> {movie?.movieYear} </div>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={likedMovie}> Like</button>
            <button> Disike</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <img class="rate-image" src = {`${movie?.moviePoster}`} />
            
        </div>
    )
  
  } 

  export default RateMovies;
```

Comment: This is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see `console.log()` 1000 times is because your `forEach()` loop updates a state variable (`popularMovies`) defined in `RateMovies()`. Every time state changes, React will re-render your component.

Instead of adding a new item one at a time, create a new array in your `forEach` loop. This will only modify state a single time, meaning the component should only re-render once.

Try something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        
        popularMoviesRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
            
            var newArray = []
    
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var data = childSnapshot.val();

                newArray.push({ 
                    key: key, 
                    movieTitle: data.movie_title, 
                    moviePoster: data.movie_poster, 
                    movieYear: data.movie_year,
                    movieGenre: data.movie_genre, 
                    movieRating: data.imdb_rating
                })
            });

            setPopularMovies([...popularMovies, ...newArray])

        }));
    }, [render]);
```

As far as your button not re-rendering the data you want, I'm not 100% sure but it may have to do with the way JavaScript handles promises. The `popularMoviesRef.once` call in your `useEffect` may be happening at the same time as your `db.collection('users').doc(user_id).update`. You can test this by adding a `console.log()` to your `useEffect` function to try to see if it logs before `"Successfully Updated!"`.

See here: [What is the order of execution in JavaScript promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises/36877743#36877743)

Comment: I get the error that snapshot.map isn't a function

Comment: @Kris you're right, I forgot ```.once()``` returns an object, not an array. It has to be done with ```forEach()```. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any insights into why the render++ needs to execute twice before the page updates?

Comment: @Kris I'm not 100% sure what is causing it, but it may have to do with how JavaScript handles ```.then()``` in a promise. I updated my answer with some related info that might be helpful.