# Functions not running in order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While running the code, I am trying to call the function addValuesForSubmission to add the row in the rows array before calling the valueSubmission function which sends the values to the database. Doing a console.log displays the value of rows and shows that the row is being added however, it is calling the valueSubmission function for submitting the values before adding the row at the end. I tried using a Promise but it is still not working.

```
  const valueSubmission = () => {
    //function to submit values to database
    var result = errorChecking();

    if (result.error === true) {
      setErrorMessage({ error: false, messages: [] });
      setSubmitError(true);
      setErrorMessage(result);
    } else {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      agreementpricesServices
        .updateAgreementPrices({ AgreementPrices: rows })
        .then(() => {
          setResubmit(!resubmit);
          setSuccess(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setSubmitError(true);
          setErrorMessage({
            error: true,
            messages: [error.response.error.error],
          });
          setResubmit(!resubmit);
        });
    }
  };

  const addValuesForSubmission = () => {
    //function to add last row to array before submitting values
    if (!isNaN(from) && !isNaN(price) && from !== "" && price !== "") {
      const data = {
        priceID: rows.length !== 0 ? rows[rows.length - 1].priceID + 1 : 1,
        agreementID: agreementID,
        from: from,
        to: to,
        price: price,
      };

      setRows((rows) => [...rows, data]);
      setNumberRecords(numberRecords + 1);
      setFrom("");
      setTo("");
      setPrice("");
      setID(id + 1);
    }
  };

  const submitValues = async (event) => {
    //function to submit values or to add new row in table
    event.preventDefault();

    const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 500);
    });

    myPromise.then(addValuesForSubmission).then(valueSubmission);
  };
```

Comment: plz take a time to learned from this answer to understand promise https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877743/2596344

Comment: In React, [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: @JulienBaldy That won't help here at all

Comment: So the `myPromise` you only added because `addValuesForSubmission(); valueSubmisson();` didn't work?

Comment: Instead of using `setRows`, simply `return` the array and pass it as an argument to `valueSubmission`

Comment: @Bergi I tried it and it worked, Thank you!

Comment: @jsejcksn I replaced the state with a normal var array with rows.push and it worked, thank you