# Understanding order of tasks in the micro queue used for promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a better understanding of the Nodejs event loop and have got to the different types of queues that are used under the covers. My question is related to the micro queue used for promises.

From everything I have read, my current understanding is that the micro queue used for promises works on a FIFO basis (first in first out). However I have a small piece of example code that doesn't make sense to me following that principle.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve();
const promise2 = Promise.resolve();

promise2.then(function p2() {
  console.log('in promise2.then()')
})
promise1.then(function p1() {
  console.log('in promise1.then()')
})
console.log('end test')
```

So from my current (quite possibly flawed understanding) of the order of events that will take place here is

1. `promise1` resolves instantly causing its handler (`p1`) to be added to the micro queue
2. `promise2` resolves instantly causing its handler (`p2`) to be added to the micro queue
3. `console.log('end test')` gets added to the stack, instantly popped resulting in the log being printed
4. Now that the stack is empty the `p1` handler is picked off the queue (FIFO) and added to the stack resulting in `in promise1.then()` being printed
5. The `p2` handler is picked off the queue and added to the stack resulting in `in promise2.then()` being printed

This would result in an output of

```
end test
in promise1.then()
in promise2.then()
```

However what I am actually getting is

```
end test
in promise2.then()
in promise1.then()
```

I've even tried to run it through a visualiser like this https://www.jsv9000.app/?code=Y29uc3QgcHJvbWlzZTEgPSBQcm9taXNlLnJlc29sdmUoKTsKY29uc3QgcHJvbWlzZTIgPSBQcm9taXNlLnJlc29sdmUoKTsKCnByb21pc2UyLnRoZW4oZnVuY3Rpb24gcDIoKSB7CiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ2luIHByb21pc2UyLnRoZW4oKScpCn0pCnByb21pc2UxLnRoZW4oZnVuY3Rpb24gcDEoKSB7CiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ2luIHByb21pc2UxLnRoZW4oKScpCn0pCmNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCdlbmQgdGVzdCcp

My understanding seems to hold up while the handlers are being added to the micro queue but then everything falls apart once it starts picking things off.

My question is how is the `p2` handler being picked off the micro queue and run before the `p1` handler if the microqueue is a FIFO system?

Comment: You've called `promise2.then` before `promise1.then`. The order of assignment of the promises to the variables has no bearing on the further operations.

Comment: see: [What is the order of execution in JavaScript promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises)

Comment: "promise1 resolves instantly" correct "causing its handler (p1) to be added to the micro queue" incorrect: there is no handler at that point. There isn't a handler until you call `.then`, and since the Promises are already resolved, you get the handlers added to the queue in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Promise [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

> Promise.resolve() resolves a promise, which is not the same as
> fulfilling or rejecting the promise

If the promise is immediately in a resolved state, nothing is added to the microtask queue. The ECMAScript Language Specification in section [27.2.4.7](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.resolve) does not indicate that any microtask job is created as a result of calling Promise.resolve()

Then, section [27.2.5.4.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen) says that if the promise is already in a resolved state when `.then` is called,

> 10. Else if promise.[[PromiseState]] is fulfilled, then c. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob

This is essentially saying that a microtask (job) is created every single time `.then` is called on a resolved promise.

We can demonstrate that it is the `.then` call which creates a microtask, by seeing what happens when we call `.then` twice on the same resolved promise:

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve();
const promise2 = Promise.resolve();

promise2.then(function p2() {
  console.log('in promise2.then()')
})
promise1.then(function p1() {
  console.log('in promise1.then()')
})
promise1.then(function p1() {
  console.log('in promise1.then() a second time')
})

console.log('this text should appear first')
```

As the output indicates, the queue is a FIFO queue. The only confusion was that the microtasks are created by `.then` calls rather then by the `Promise.resolve()` calls, because the promises are already resolved.

You can see it work in the originally expected order if the promises are only resolved after the `.then` calls:

```js
const refs = {};
const promise1 = new Promise(resolve => refs.resolveP1 = resolve);
const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => refs.resolveP2 = resolve);

promise1.then(function p1() {
  console.log('in promise1.then()')
})
promise2.then(function p2() {
  console.log('in promise2.then()')
})
promise1.then(function p1() {
  console.log('in promise1.then() a second time')
})

refs.resolveP1();
refs.resolveP2();

console.log('this text should appear first')
```

This time, when `.then` is called, the callback functions are added to the PromiseFulfillReactions list for the promise, and are not invoked until something causes the promise to become resolved:

> 9. If promise.[[PromiseState]] is pending, then a. Append fulfillReaction to promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]].

Note that in the output of the preceding example, the two P1 messages appear first, even though the `.then` calls are not in that order. This is because they are in the PromiseFulfillReactions list for P1, and all execute at the time that P1 is resolved.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. So just to confirm - If a promise is already fulfilled when `.then()` is called it is the `.then()` call that adds the handler to the microqueue. If a promise is not fulfilled when `.then()` is called, the handler is added to the PromiseFulfillReactions list and then once the promise fulfills that handler is then added to the microqueue?

Comment: @Wodlo to be a little more specific, it's a job that is added to the microtask queue, which will invoke the handler. If `.then` is called on a pending promise, the handler is just added to the PromiseFulfillReactions list. But if the promise is resolved when `.then` is called, a microtask is instantly created which will invoke the handler when executed

Comment: Thanks again, I think I understand now. I believe the biggest bit of information missing from my initial understanding was the existence of the PromiseFulfillReactions list. After reading your reply I did some further reading and found this article extremely helpful https://medium.com/swlh/order-of-execution-of-javascript-promises-with-examples-f2e8f81138b7 as it explicitly walks through the state of the PromiseFulfillReactions list. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

When the promises in your example resolve, there are no handlers yet. The promises are simply immediately fulfilled with `undefined`, then assigned to their respective variables.

Only after that, you are calling `.then()` on the promises and passing in the handlers. Since the promises are already fulfilled by then, the handlers immediately get scheduled - and since you are doing `promise2.then(p2)` before `promise1.then(p1)`, `p2` comes first in the queue and is executed first.

Either way, it should not matter. This kind of asynchronous code does not appear in the wild, where every promise is resolved as soon as possible, and independent promise chains race against each other so their order is unpredictable. If you cared about the order, you'd make them depend on each other.