# (Javascript) Browser async code vs async code that runs on the main thread

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the behaviour of asynchronous code in JS. Consider the following code.

```
async function longTask() {
    let i=0;
    while(true){
            i++
            if(i === 6000000000){
            return "completed a long operation"
        }
    }
}

console.log("start")
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))

longTask().then(result => console.log(result))
console.log("end")
```

The above code yeilds output:

```
start
// after about 7-8 seconds
end
completed a long operation
{ API call result }
```

(To yeild the output, I used chrome's devTools console)

If I go by event loop concepts as explained [nicely in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30910084), the "fetch" function is pushed into the macro task Q, and then the "longTask()" call should also be pushed into the macro call Q since it is an async code that internally returns a promise. My goal with this longTask function is to simulate an async code that resolves later than the fetch call, but actually runs on the main thread unlike the fetch.

Looking at the output, its clear that longTask is being executed via the call stack and not the macro Q (because the "end" console.log is also being printed after a huge delay).

Is this true? In this example, did the call to "longTask" actually did not get added to the macro Q, and rather got pushed in the call stack?

I dont think "longTask" got executed like a normal function (because if it did, the statement "long task completed" would have ran before "end"). But if I assume that "longTask" was added to the macro task Q, it means "fetch" was added before it. And the code is setup such that fetch will always resolve its promise before the longTask. Which means fetch's callback get added to the micro Q earlier than longTask's. But that is also not the case. "longTask"s callback got executed before fetch's.

Please explain what's going on or if there is something wrong in my understanding of the concept.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: use a Promise with a setTimeout ... what you're emulating there is poor coding effecting the UI

Comment: I know that the code is poor and that adding a setTimeout fixes the code. I am trying to understand the behaviour of the code as it stands.

Comment: the fact that the loop is inside an `async` function doesn't change the fact that once that code is executing, nothing else can execute until it's done - think of javascript as being single threaded (because it technically is)

Comment: but then why the "end" prints before "long task completion".

Comment: because `longTask` is `async`

Comment: but then why the "end" prints before "long task completion" - That's a race condition. The Promise its callback is scheduled to run slightly after. But making your method `async` doesn't make it async. It just allows `await` operators. Also javascript is still single-threaded

Answer (score 0):

When fetch() is called, the I/O begins, and a pending promise is returned. When it eventually completes, a macrotask is added to the macrotask queue.

Without waiting for the I/O to complete, longTask() is then called. Since there are no async API calls inside longTask() which require macrotasks to be created, it therefore runs immediately and in its entirety as if it was not an async method, except that the return value is a fulfilled promise rather than a string.

When `.then()` is called on the longTask fulfilled promise, this creates a microtask which is added to the microtask queue (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410570/understanding-order-of-tasks-in-the-micro-queue-used-for-promises/76410737#76410737) answer). The microtask queue has priority over the macrotask queue, which is why you see the result of `longTask()` printed to the console before the result of `fetch` is printed.

If, instead, longTask() used setTimeout(), then that would mean the longTask() function would not execute immediately in its entirety, and would create a macrotask on completion. This means that if longTask took longer than the fetch, the results of fetch() would appear on the console first.

Comment: By the above example, I tried to emulate the following point:

Given 2 promises A and B such that JS encounters promise A first and B later. Since the "then" callbacks of both promises (then-A and then-B) are micro tasks, and it is given that promise A will resolve before promise B, then then-A will execute before then-B. Atleast in theory. But the output I get doesnt indicate that.


"""When it eventually completes, a macrotask is added to the macrotask queue."""


For the fetch, the "then" should add a micro task too, I think.

Comment: @LakshayDutta `.then()` only creates a microtask if the promise was created as a fulfilled promise (which happens when an otherwise ordinary method is marked as async but does not await anything). If you awaited an API call (such as I/O or setTimeout), then the callback is placed on the macrotask queue. This is why code that awaits an API call behaves differently. Please add your new code to the question if you'd like me to look at it.