How is the order of Promise's Handler (then - catch - finally) push into MicroTask queue in Javascript?

[Case 1]

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('Error!');
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(3);
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))



Result of expect: 1 - Error! - 3
Result of actual: 1 - 3 - Error!

=> When push Promise's Handler into MicroTask queue, I think there is a priority: .then() > .catch()

[Case 2.1]

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
})
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 1'))
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('Error!');
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 2'))

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(3);
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 3'))


Result of expect: Promise settled! 1 - Error! - 3 - 1 - Promise settled! 2 - Promise settled! 3
Result of actual: Promise settled! 1 - 3 - Error! - Promise settled! 2 - Promise settled! 3 - 1

=> When push Promise's Handler into MicroTask queue, I think there is a priority: .finally() > .then() > .catch()

[Case 2.2]

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
})
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 1'))
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('Error! 2');
})
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 2'))
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('Error! 3');
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 3'))

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(4);
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => console.log('Promise settled! 4'))



Result of expect: Promise settled! Promise settled! 1 - Promise settled! 2 - Error! 3 - 4 - 1 - Error! 2 - Promise settled! 3 - Promise settled! 4
Result of actual: Promise settled! Promise settled! 1 - Promise settled! 2 - 4 - Error! 3 - Promise settled! 3 - Promise settled! 4 - 1 - Error! 2

=> When push Promise's Handler into MicroTask queue, I think there is a priority: .finally() > .then() > .catch()
I don't know if my thinking is correct? Hope you guys have experience explaining how it works. Many thanks!

it may help you to know that .then and .catch and .finally return a Promise - also, one usually wouldn't put .finally before .then or .catch like that - since finally is analogous to the finally of try/catch/finally, i.e. it would handle (in one function) both rejected and resolved promises - usually to do some sort of "clean up" - given the order you use .then/.catch/.finally you will see some variation in the output

in short, .then, .catch and .finally result in a new Promise that is added to the microtask queue - the order is significant

"Case 1, case 2.1, case 2.2": Your question is too broad. Please focus on one issue only.

According to the explanation of @Andrew Parks (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410570/understanding-order-of-tasks-in-the-micro-queue-used-for-promises), these above cases still cannot be explained

Please focus your question on one case. It is currently too broad.
