# Is `Promise.resolve().then(f)` equivalent to `Promise.resolve(f())`?

Tags: javascript, github, jestjs, promise, pull-request

In the codebase of [async-pool](https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool/pull/48/files), there is this statement:

```
const p = Promise.resolve(iteratorFn(item, iterable));
```

I believe that this statement is equivalent to:

```
const p = Promise.resolve().then(() => iteratorFn(item, iterable));
```

...as both statements resolve a promise and execute `iteratorFn(item, iterable)` asynchronously.

I would like to confirm if my assumption is correct and understand how I can validate it. I would then write appropriate unit tests to ensure the behavior of this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

> both statements resolve a promise and execute `iteratorFn(item, iterable)` asynchronously.

This is not true. The original code:

```
const p = Promise.resolve(iteratorFn(item, iterable));
```

...executes `iteratorFn` synchronously. In other words, first `iteratorFn` is executed, then `resolve`, and then `p` is assigned the resolved promise.

While here:

```
 const p = Promise.resolve().then(() => iteratorFn(item, iterable));
```

`resolve` is called first, then `then` and then a pending(!) promise is assigned to `p`. Code will then continue with whatever next statement is to be executed synchronously. The callback that has been passed to `then()` will be called when the engine processes its microtask queue, so after the call stack is empty. Then `iteratorFn` will get executed, which will resolve the promise `p`.

We can see the difference in behaviour in this snippet:

```js
function iteratorFn(arg) {
    console.log("running iteratorFn with argument " + arg);
}

console.log("executing original code");
const p = Promise.resolve(iteratorFn("p")); 
console.log("p has been assigned");

console.log("executing customised code");
const q = Promise.resolve().then(() => iteratorFn("q")); 
console.log("q has been assigned");
console.log("------------- end of synchronous code -----------------");
```

Comment: …and more importantly, if `iteratorFn` throws, the one expression produces an exception and the other produces a rejected promise

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that brings me to another interesting question.  ```Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(0);
    return Promise.resolve(4);
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(1);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(2);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(3);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(5);
}).then(() =>{
    console.log(6);
})
```

Comment: See [What is the order of execution in JavaScript promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36870467/5459839) and the many other Q&A with varying scenarios.