# Promise.resolve with no arguments

Tags: javascript, promise

I know a [similar question was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977589/promise-resolve-with-no-argument-passed-in) but it doesn't quite answer what I'm trying to understand.

I'm reading the [mobx-state-router tutorial](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/mobx-state-router) and it has this piece of code:

```
{
    name: 'department',
    pattern: '/departments/:id',
    onEnter: (fromState, toState, routerStore) => {
        const { rootStore: { itemStore } } = routerStore;
        itemStore.loadDepartmentItems(toState.params.id);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
},
```

I don't understand what this `Promise.resolve()` relates to? Which promise is it? How/when is it resolved?

Comment: It's just a dummy `Promise` that resolves immediately. Seems that the caller of `onEnter` expects a Promise to be returned.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - oh, now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` is the same as `Promise.resolve(undefined)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which promise is it?

`Promise.resolve` creates a *new* promise.

> How/when is it resolved?

Immediately, that's what `Promise.resolve` is for.

`onEnter` is apparently expected to return a promise. In this particular `onEnter`, it doesn't have any asynchronous work to do, so it returns a pre-resolved promise. Normally, you specify the value the promise should be resolved with (`Promise.resolve(42)`), but if you don't, the usual JavaScript semantics apply and the value that is used to resolve the promise is the value `undefined`.

See `Promise.resolve` [in the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.resolve) and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Comment: Thanks! Now I see. It's related to the expectation by the caller.

Comment: @Avi for the same reasons there is `Promise.reject(...)`