# JS: What to a resolve a promise to when you don't care about the return value?

Tags: javascript

If I want to use a Promise to ensure a function is run first but don't care what the return is, what do I resolve it to?  Is it best practice to `resolve(true)`?

```
let getShoes = return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something 
    //resolve(true);  resolve using true?
});

getShoes.then(() => {
    // do something else but don't need the return from getShoes...only need to ensure it is run first
})
```

Comment: No need for `return new Promise`...just `return fetch`. fetch is promise based.

Comment: true @David784 .  What about if it wasn't using fetch and rather just doing a calculation first where I didn't care about the return but just wanted to make sure it ran first?

Comment: I edited the question to make it w/o making an API call

Comment: I think that undefined is better, in async function undefined is the default returned value, just like regular functions

Comment: It's been a while back, (node 8 maybe?) but I once had a node.js project where I tried just calling `resolve()` with no value (undefined), and weird things happened. When I added a return value, the weirdness stopped. Might've just been a bug, and maybe it's not an issue any more. But ever since then I always make sure to have some value in resolve and reject, even if it's just a boolean or integer or whatever. Just my $0.02

Comment: Ohh didn’t know that @David784

Answer (score 1):

I will choose to return undefined.

A function without return statement or with empty return statement always return undefined

The same happens with async functions.

If you resolve with empty resolve() you get undefined as fulfillment value.

Answer (score -1):

Resolving to `true` sounds reasonable to me because you'll explicitly state that you don't care about the return value of the promise.

You could also invoke `resolve()` without parameters as in [Promise.resolve with no argument passed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977589/promise-resolve-with-no-argument-passed-in), which will resolve to `undefined`. By doing that, you will again be stating that you don't care about the value.

Comment: I didn't explicitly mention that calling `resolve()` without parameters returns `undefined`, but it is mentioned in the thread that I linked to. I edited the answer to include that part