# Micro and macro tasks in JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, event-loop

[There are micro- and macro- task queues in the JavaScript runtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context)

`setTimeout` uses the macrotask queue.

`setImmediate` in IE11 presumably uses the microtask queue?

`process.nextTick` uses the microtask queue.

But `setImmediate` is not implemented in any other browser (and won't be AFAIK).

And `process.nextTick` is Node only.

Promises use the micro task queue. Could `Promise` therefore be leveraged to provide `setImmediate` like functionality in non IE browsers?

Comment: You could also utilize the [`MutationObserver` API](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three years later, of course, but we do have an answer for this now: the [`window.queueMicrotask()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) method has been added to allow adding a callback to the JavaScript runtime's microtask queue. I'm currently working on fleshing out a [microtask guide on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide).