# What's the difference between Promise.resolve().then() vs. setTimeout for Scheduling Asynchronous Tasks?

Tags: javascript, queue, settimeout, es6-promise

In Javascript, I've ran into an example that creates a batching process via
an asynchronous call with `Promise.resolve().then(runDownTheQueue)` in pseudocode it looks something like:

```
function queueEverythingUp (addMeToQueue) {
  if (queueIsEmpty) {
    Promise.resolve().then(runDownTheQueue);
  }
  addToQueue(addMeToQueue);
}
```

This is just a method for setting up batches to be run in a queue.

My question is, how does the use of a Promise differ from this approach to asynchronous scheduling:

```
function queueEverythingUp (addMeToQueue) {
  if (queueIsEmpty) {
    setTimeout(() => {runDownTheQueue()}, 0);
  }
  addToQueue(addMeToQueue);
}
```

In both cases it seems that the execution of running down the queue is asynchronously deferred until the queue is built up via synchronous calls to queueEverythingUp.

Is the only difference the internal workings of how Promises and setTimeouts interact with the Javascript engine?

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout

Comment: @palash sounds like a good dupe

Comment: Microtask vs. macrotask is what I was looking for. This is a duplicate question. Can't delete it tho...

Comment: analogous question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout/ , short answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455210/2836443