# Promise within for loop accessing correct value within closure

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

Anyone has any insight on why the following code works?
Notice it's still using `var` in loop rather than `let`.

```
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(i);
    resolve();
  });
}
// Output: 0,1,2,3,4
```

---

We know that if `setTimout` is used here, it queues up 5 macrotasks and will reference `i` in closure after loop is done, printing out all 5's eventually.

But if promise is being used here, why the microtask queue can accurately scope the `var i` value?

Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise vs setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 2):

Though I was unable to find any direct citation explaining this it has been my experience that the executor function to a Promise constructor is executed **synchronously**.

Though it provides the `resolve` and `reject` functions as callbacks to manage any asynchronous code being evaluated or queued within the executor function the executor function itself is not only synchronous but also executed synchronously in the greater context of the Promise object being instantiated.

That would explain why the `console.log` will log in order within that loop but using a `setTimeout` would be performed deferred after the variable `i` has since moved on to its final value.

Comment: Found citation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118995/227176

Answer (score 2):

That happens because that code never gets executed in any microtask. The promise executor is called inside the `Promise` constructor function, only the `then` callbacks are called inside a microtask.

You can see this if you run this code:

```js
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log("Hi from the promise executor!");
  res();
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Hi from the `then` callback (from a microtask)");
});
console.log("Stack emptied");
```

So your code is equivalent to this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(i);
    // resolve();
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, Promise callback argument is invoked synchronously, so there's no surprise in there, but regarding this statement:

> We know that if `setTimout` is used here, it queues up 5 macrotasks and will reference `i` in closure after loop is done, printing out all 5's eventually.

This is wrong.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  setTimeout(console.log, 0, i);
```

You can schedule with both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` not just callbacks, but the value these callbacks will receive as parameters.

That means that the `for` loop in there will log `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`, in this exact order.

Comment: I think the OP meant `setTimeout(() => { console.log(i); });`

Comment: possible, but that's just the wrong choice when you want to forward values to the callback you are scheduling, and it's a very common mistake/misconception of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` usage.

Answer (score 0):

For a fair comparison, you would want to place the console.log within the resolve like this

```
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(console.log(i));
  });
}
```

Still, this would yield the same results because there is no async delay. But then why does a setTimeout that has 0 delay not produce the same result?

NodeJS has a first in last out callstack, with each cycle referred to as a tick. When a setTimeout resolves, it gets placed in the message queue, which doesn't run until the next tick. When a promise resolves, it gets to cut back in line immediately within the current tick.

The call stacks therefor look like

setTimeout:

```
timeout i ++ > timeout > i ++ > timeout > i ++ > timeout > i ++ > timeout > i ++ > log > log > log > log > log
```

promise:

```
promise > resolve > log > i++ > promise > resolve > log > i++ > promise > resolve > log > i++ > promise > resolve > log > i++ > promise > resolve > log > i++
```

So you can see that by the time the console.logs within setTimeout are called, i has already been equated to 5, where as the promise console.logs get to cut back in line before i is iterated.

```js
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout( ()=> {
    console.log("setTimeout:",i);
  });
}

for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(console.log("Promise:",i));
  });
}
```

Also notice that the Promise console.logs occur before setTimeout console.logs even though the setTimeout loop occurs first. This shows the current tick includes both for loops, so any setTimeout console.log has to wait until they both complete.