# Two Different Implementations of Code Involving Time Delay in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, settimeout

I have a quick question about two different implementations of code in a react native app. I'd like to know if and why one is considered better than the other and why.

#1 uses a standard `setTimeout` within `componentDidMount()` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ editable: true });
  }, 2000);
}
```

The second one also involves waiting, but looks like this:

```
const wait = (timeout) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
}

componentDidMount() {
  wait(2000).then(() => {
    this.setState({ editable: true });
  });
}
```

Does the second implementation do something the first does not? Is one more robust than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your first question

Does the second implementation do something the first does not?

**Besides promise being faster, Both are exactly the same.**

Is one more robust than the other?

the second one is more common in a lot of frameworks and libraries as it provides a better way of chaining with a nice way of `catch`ing errors

for more info
[Promise vs setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout)

for example
in `react-testing-library` there is `waitForElementToBeRemoved`