# How async await works in JavaScript with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

Why this code does not work

I want to learn the synchronization in the easy way

```
const post = [];

function getPost(post) {
     console.log(post)
 }

async function createPost (post) {
  await setTimeout(() => {
    post.push({
      name: "John", work: "Developer"
    })
  }, 1000)
  getPost(post);
}

createPost(post);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work because `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise. If you `await` a non-Promise, you just get the value (almost¹) immediately. You'd also want to consume the promise returned by `createPost`, which your code isn't currently doing.

You'd have to make a wrapper for `setTimeout` that returns a promise, for instance [as shown in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22707551/157247), although these days I'd modify it a bit:

```
function timeout(delay, ...args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay, ...args);
    });
}
```

Here's that applied to your code, although I assume the `setTimeout` in your code is really a stand-in for some other async operation (ajax, MongoDB, etc.), and I wouldn't structure the code this way (I'd have `post` created and returned by `createPost` rather than being an array that `createPost` closes over):

```js
function timeout(delay, ...args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay, args);
    });
}

const post = [];

function getPost(post) {
    console.log(post)
}

async function createPost(post) {
  await timeout(1000);
  post.push({
      name: "John", work: "Developer"
  });
  getPost(post);
}

// Going async at top level
(async () => {
    await createPost(post);
})().catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

---

¹ *"almost immediately"* `a = await b; ...` is syntactic sugar (really, really good sugar) for `Promise.resolve(b).then(a => ...)` (plus error handling). If `b` isn't a promise, the assignment to `a` happens in the microtask processing following the task the `await` occurs in. More about tasks and microtasks in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39139643/157247).