# JavaScript ES6 - Possible race condition between promise resolution and event?

Tags: javascript, race-condition, es6-promise

Is it possible to have user code executed between a promise resolution and a promise await return?

```
function a () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Between here...
      resolve()
    }, 1000))
  }
}

async function b () {
  await a()
  // ...and here ?
}
```

Does the specification enforces that Promise callbacks are called immediatly? I wonder if an event could be handled by the virtual machine between the 2 points, possibly causing side-effects.

Comment: Sure, that is what *asynchronous* means. Other events may happen interspersed between events.

Comment: Not an *event*, but other promise callbacks might run between there.

Comment: @deceze I understand that anything could happen while b is waiting for a, but my question is specifically about between promise resolution and callbacks invocation.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you indeed if the Promise has several callbacks multiple will be called, so I have to be aware of that. For the event part do you have any source?

Comment: @Yovar Haven't found anything better than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25915634/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I suppose it works like the job system James Thorpe [refers to in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45299328/7243207).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't enforce immediate calling.  [The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) runs through a number of steps upon resolving a promise, one of which is:

> 12. Perform EnqueueJob ("PromiseJobs", PromiseResolveThenableJob, «‍promise, resolution, thenAction»)

Note that depending on the state of the promise, different routes can be taken.  However, they all [end at EnqueueJob](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enqueuejob), which says:

> 8. Add pending at the back of the Job Queue named by queueName.

So any further executions are deferred to the end of the job queue.

Answer (score 2):

Promise callbacks are **not** called immediately. Your function `b()` transforms to

```
function b () {
  return a().then(() => {
    // Do something
  });
}
```

where the function which is given to `then` is executed at some point of time by the eventloop **after** the promise from `a` was resolved. It will never be called synchronously, because the specification guarantees that Promise continuations always run with an empty call stack (which means in a fresh iteration of the eventloop). Therefore some other code (e.g. from another promise resolval) can run between the time where the promise was resolved and when the continuation runs.