# Polymers this.async vs Promise.then vs setTimeout

Tags: asynchronous, polymer, settimeout, es6-promise, event-loop

Whats the difference between Polymers this.async, Promise.then and setTimeout function?

My understanding:

this.async and Promise.then moves a Task to the end of the current Stack and setTimeout is handled as new Task and executed in the next loop when the eventloop takes a new task from the queue?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: [this](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) or [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/writing-a-javascript-framework-execution-timing-beyond-settimeout/) might be helpful reads

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:** Yes, but note `this.async` [uses `setTimeout`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/e2d8446/src/lib/async.html#L22) if a timeout is specified.

---

- `Polymer.Async.run` (`this.async`) *without timeout* - queues a **micro**task (via a `MutationObserver` callback)
- `Polymer.Async.run` (`this.async`) *with timeout* - queues a **macro**task
- `Promise.then` - queues a microtask
- `setTimeout` - queues a macrotask

[Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933985/6277151)

Comment: this.async queues a microtask and Promise.then creates a microtask? Is there a difference between - queues and creates?

Comment: Things are named (i.e. namespaced) a bit more explicitly starting with Polymer 2: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/lib/utils/async.html -- You decide, via `Polymer.Async.[namespace].run`, which functionality you want.

Comment: @simplesystems in that context, there's no difference between *queue* and *create*.