# what works before on eventloop?Microtasks or macrotasks?

Tags: javascript

I'm investigating the event loop. But I ran into a question. What works before on eventloop? Microtasks or macrotasks?
if I run the following code

```
Promise.resolve().then(()=> console.log('Promise'));
setTimeOut(()=>console.log("setTimeout"),0);
```

console.log show "Promise setTimeout";
but according to an answer [Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context)
Macrotasks works before microtask.

Answer (score 0):

`Macrotasks` are processed before other `microtasks`, but after a macrotask finishes all of the microtasks that are scheduled are going to run. A corollary of this is that 2 macrotasks cannot run one after another if there are some microtasks already scheduled.

Your current JS loop run (where you're running `Promise` and `setTimeout`) is actually a `Macrotask`. `Promise` schedules a microtask and `setTimeout` a macrotask.

When the current script ends, a `Macrotask` ends and the runtime looks into the microtask queue. It resolves the `Promise` and, if no other microtasks are scheduled from this run it will run the next `Macrotask`. In your case this is the `setTimeout` method.

Comment: What do you mead on this "When the current script ends, a Macrotask ends and the runtime looks into the microtask queue".Which Macrotask ended?

Comment: The current script that was running is actually a macrotask. That's the macrotask that ended.

Comment: Is all script on random page at first one macrotask? Right?

Comment: Yes, the initial script and whatever you run in the console is run as a macrotask.