# In which phase of Nodejs event loop resolved promises' callbacks get executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325561) :

> "And the important thing is taking into account that then/catch
> callbacks in a promise are microtasks and will be executed after
> nextTick tasks"

Nodejs docs mentions that nextTickQueue will be processed after the current operation is completed, regardless of the current phase of the event loop. Does that mean resolved promises callbacks does execute in neither poll phase not pending callbacks phase?

Also, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YgsqXlUoTM) mentions that there is a queueMicroTask queue which is processed after the current phase of the event loop. So what I understand now is :

Resolved promises callbacks will be added to queueMicroTask which will be processed  after the nextTickQueue (Callbacks passed to process.nextTick) which will be processed after whatever the current phase of the event loop is.

Is that correct? If it's not please correct me, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an important semantic with microtasks and nextTicks which depends on the Node version.

**Before Node v11,** nextTick queue was executed between each phase of the event loop (timers, I/O, immediates, close handlers are the four phases). Therefore, before Node v11, promise callbacks were also executed between each phase in the event loop. (I've written about this in detail here: https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa)

**However, starting from Node v11,** event loop jumps to `microtask` queue whenever a `microtask` is added to the microtask queue as part of the execution of the program. You can experiment this with the following snippet. The same applies to nextTick queue too. You can read more here: https://blog.insiderattack.net/new-changes-to-timers-and-microtasks-from-node-v11-0-0-and-above-68d112743eb3

```js
setImmediate(() => console.log('timeout1'));
setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('timeout2')
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise'))
});
setImmediate(() => console.log('timeout3'));
setImmediate(() => console.log('timeout4'));
```

The output of the above code changes depending on the Node.js version as follows:

```bash
$ node -v
v10.19.0
$ node test.js    
timeout1
timeout2
timeout3
timeout4
promise

$ nvm use 11
Now using node v11.15.0 (npm v6.7.0)
$ node test.js        
timeout1
timeout2
promise
timeout3
timeout4
```

**Therefore it's important to know that**: `nextTicks` and `microtasks` have an even higher priority in Node versions >=11, because they get the chance to be processed within the current phase of the event loop. But in earlier Node versions, `nextTicks` and `microtasks` are executed at the end of each phase of the loop.

> On a side note, it's important to know that `microtasks` queue is a part of `v8` engine and not maintained in Node.js runtime. However, Node.js event loop instructs `v8` to run all `microtasks`, once Node.js finishes with the `nextTick` queue. Therefore, promise callbacks are executed after `nextTick` queue.

Answer (score 2):

> Nodejs docs mentions that nextTickQueue will be processed after the
> current operation is completed, regardless of the current phase of the
> event loop. Does that mean resolved promises callbacks does execute in
> neither poll phase not pending callbacks phase?

It's sort of an ambiguous message for sure. They can run at either phase but they are not exclusive to a particular phase.

> Resolved promises callbacks will be added to queueMicroTask which will
> be processed after the nextTickQueue (Callbacks passed to
> process.nextTick) which will be processed after whatever the current
> phase of the event loop is.

Not at the end of each phase, it could happen at any point during any phase (as I understand it).

Say you have two timers which have expired and you are at the timer expired phase of the event loop. Meaning there's two callbacks to deal with during this phase. Lets assume the first timer calls `then` on a promise which has already resolved (it can get to it right away). If this was fired at the end of the phase, then the second timer callback would run before since it's not the end of the phase yet.

What really happens here though is that the first timer callback runs and adds the callback to the microtask queue which gets consumed right AFTER the callback finishes and BEFORE continuing down the current event loop phases.

An example you can run:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first');
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    p.then(() => console.log('second'));
    p.then(() => console.log('third'));
}, 1)

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('fourth')
}, 1);
```

Comment: I really don't understand the last part of answer:


**What really happens here though is that the first timer callback runs and adds the callback to the microtask queue which gets consumed right AFTER the callback finishes and BEFORE continuing down the current event loop phases.**


Also, what if the promise doesn't resolve right away. Will the microtask queue be processed between the phases?

Comment: @rayanJ if the promise isn't resolved right away then there's no reason to run any `then` handlers during this phase because it's not ready. This means it wouldn't run in between the first timer or the second timer, unless you resolve the promise using `process.nextTick`. Once the promise resolves, barring a pending `process.nextTick` task, its handlers will run on the next stack.

Comment: Keep in mind a promise can resolve within a timeout callback or during polling (like `fetch` promises do) or any other phase really. However, any `then` handlers are not run at the same stack as the promise resolves. It instead tries to run at the next tick.