# State of Macrotask and Microtask queue during this calculation

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

This question is very similar in intent to [Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25915634/530634), but more specific, in that it asks for the explication of a definite example: I think for this reason it shouldn't be considered a duplicate.

What is the state Macrotask queue and Microtask queue during the execution of this code in node.js

```
console.log("A1");

(async ()=> {

    console.log("1")

    f = async ()=>{console.log('2')}

    await f()

    console.log("3")

})()

console.log("A2");
```

Output:

```
A1
1
2
A2
3
```

Output I expected:
A1, A2, '1','2','3'

Based on this reasoning: log A1 --> enqueue anonymous function on microtask queue --> log A2 --> execute anaonymous function log 1, enqueue f on the microtask queue --> execute f from microtask queue --> log 2 --> log 3

Where am I going wrong? (additionally how is a top level async func enqueued?)

NOTE: actual command used to run this was npx babel-node myscript.js

Comment: Just was, no reason, I'm using babel for something else and happened to use it here

Comment: (For lurkers: The Babel output is also what up-to-date Node.js does with this code natively.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because an `async` function runs **synchronously** up until the first `await`, explicit `return`, or implicit `return` (code execution falling off the end of the function).

I'm going to change the code slightly to give the outer `async` function a name so it's easier to talk about:

```
console.log("A1");
const outer = async () => {
    console.log("1")
    f = async ()=>{console.log('2')}
    await f()
    console.log("3")
};
outer();
console.log("A2");
```

Here's what happens:

1. `console.log("A1")` runs (of course).
2. `outer()` is called.
3. The synchronous part of `outer` runs, so it:

   - Runs the `console.log("1")`
   - Creates `f`
   - Calls `f()`
4. The synchronous part of `f` runs, so it:

   - Does `console.log('2')`
5. At this point, `f` implicitly returns, and so it returns its promise to `outer`. That promise is already fulfilled with the value `undefined`. (See [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start) in the spec.)
6. `outer` awaits `f`'s promise, so it returns its promise to the caller (which throws it away, but that doesn't matter).
7. `outer` awaiting `f`'s promise queued a microtask to continue `outer` because `f`'s promise is already settled.
8. `console.log("A2")` runs.
9. The microtask runs, allowing `outer` to continue and do `console.log("3")`.

Comment: What do you mean by implicit await or return, does an implicit await mean waiting for a promise to resolve?

Comment: @tjb - Sorry, the "(implicit or explicit)" referred only to `return`, I'll see if I can rephrase. An explicit return is, of course, `return;` or `return value;`. An implicit return is just code execution reaching the end of the function, as `f` and `outer` both do.

Comment: @tjb - I've updated to handle that implicit or explicit thing and add more detail.

Comment: thanks, I think I'm starting to get this,...but I've thought that alot of times already :)

Comment: @tjb - LOL, been there!