# Where can I find the complete list of items added to MicroTask Queue?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

I am following up after reading the post [Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context)

The examples posted are

```
macrotasks: setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate, requestAnimationFrame, I/O, UI rendering
microtasks: process.nextTick, Promises, Object.observe, MutationObserver
```

I am wondering where can I find the list of tasks added to the **microtask** queue in the official documents

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint

> When a user agent is to perform a microtask checkpoint:
>
> 1. If the event loop's performing a microtask checkpoint is true, then
>      return.
> 2. Set the event loop's performing a microtask checkpoint to true.
> 3. While the event loop's microtask queue is not empty:
>
>    3.1 Let oldestMicrotask be the result of dequeuing from the event loop's
>      microtask queue.
>
>    3.2 Set the event loop's currently running task to oldestMicrotask.
>
>    3.3 Run oldestMicrotask.
>
>    This might involve invoking scripted callbacks, which eventually calls
>      the clean up after running script steps, which call this perform a
>      microtask checkpoint algorithm again, which is why we use the
>      performing a microtask checkpoint flag to avoid reentrancy.
>
>    3.4 Set the event loop's currently running task back to null.
> 4. For each environment settings object whose responsible event loop is
>      this event loop, notify about rejected promises on that environment
>      settings object.
> 5. Cleanup Indexed Database transactions.
> 6. Set the event loop's performing a microtask checkpoint to false.
>
> When an algorithm running in parallel is to await a stable state, the
>   user agent must queue a microtask that runs the following steps, and
>   must then stop executing (execution of the algorithm resumes when the
>   microtask is run, as described in the following steps):
>
> Run the algorithm's synchronous section.
>
> Resumes execution of the algorithm in parallel, if appropriate, as
>   described in the algorithm's steps.
>
> Steps in synchronous sections are marked with ⌛.

Comment: This does not list what all tasks are added as Microtasks