# Who is first between macrotask and microtask in javascript?

Tags: javascript, task-queue, event-loop

I'm confused which task is taken first by event loop.

The reason is like below.

**Stackoverflow answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context)**

> After this macrotask has finished, all available microtasks will be
>   processed

**Similar example from [this](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) blog article**

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log('Macro task'), 0);
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Micro task'));
```

So, it is very confusing for me. What I understood till now is this.

1. Code that is not callback function is inserted into call stack right away.
2. Callback function of `setTimeout()` is inserted into Macro Task Queue.
3. Callback function of `Promise` is inserted into Micro Task Queue.
4. When call stack is empty, event loop takes task from Micro Task Queue and runs.
5. After execution of all micro tasks, event loop takes task from Macro Task Queue and runs.

This process is my understanding and am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Micro-task queue is checked right after the script finishes, I think. It is before the checking of macro-task queue.

See [here](https://javascript.info/event-loop) for detailed information.

Answer (score 2):

> Because **the script itself is treated as a macrotask** so that at the end the enqueued microtasks are executed.

So the promise is a microtask, setTimeout callback is a macrotask, but the script is a macrotask as well.

As a result, **script -> promise -> setTimeout**

More details here: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-event-loop-y-promises-951ba6845899