# Can somebody explain how this code is executed in relation to the call stack and the event loop?

Tags: javascript, callstack, event-loop

I have created this snippet which I am trying to figure out how it's working the way it's working.

```js
function fetch() {
  console.log("Fetch start");

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Executor");

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Timeout");

      resolve("Resolved value");
    }, 1000);
  }).then(value => {
    console.log("Fetch end", { value });

    return { value };
  });
}

function stuff() {
  console.log("Stuff start");

  fetch().then(value => {
    console.log("Stuff end", value);
  });
}

stuff();

console.log("Sync log");
```

The way I see it:

1. `stuff()` is pushed onto the call stack. Code inside of it is executed line by line.
2. `console.log('Stuff start')` is added onto the call stack, executes, then popped off.
3. `fetch()` function is called, it gets pushed onto the call stack on top of `stuff()`, so now we're inside this function's body.
4. `console.log('Fetch start')` executes.
5. `new Promise()` constructor is used to create a new promise object and since the constructor is basically a function, it gets added onto the call stack, which looks like this at this point: `GEC => stuff() => fetch() => new Promise()`. The promise constructor receives a callback as argument (I think it's called executor), which is ran when a new promise is created, so in this case I assume that the executor is also added onto the call stack on top of `new Promise()`. Now the callstack looks like `GEC => stuff() => fetch() => new Promise() => executor`.
6. `console.log('Executor')` runs, aka added onto the call stack then popped off when it's done.
7. `setTimeout()` runs and pushed onto the call stack, it sends the callback to the web APIs, which set up a timer. When the timer is done, the callback will be added to the task queue. Now `setTimeout` has ran its purpose, so it's popped off the call stack.

Now this is where it goes blurry for me and I don't know how to check in the Chrome Devtools either.

Next, `console.log('Sync log')` is ran, so I assume whatever's been on the call stack so far finish executing. After one second, the callback in `setTimeout` is added from the task queue onto the callstack.

Inside this callback, resolve() is pushed and popped off the call stack, which leads to `then()` to be able to run, somehow. Then once `then` is done executing, the control seems to return to `stuff()`.

I don't know if I understood this correctly, so please, correct me if I'm wrong and I would greatly appreciate it if someone gave me an explanation.

Comment: Protip: don't name your global functions the same as existing [global functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are the callbacks of promises put in the micro task queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195441/how-are-the-callbacks-of-promises-put-in-the-micro-task-queue)

Comment: and a very clear explanation here: [What is the order of execution in JavaScript promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises)

Comment: One the timer is scheduled, fulfilment handler is registered on the promise and the `then` promise is returned. On the returned promise, `then` method is called to register a fulfillment handler. Once that is done, `stuff` function is done. Next, `Sync log` is logged and with that, the synchronous execution of the script ends. Now the event loop can start processing the asynchronous tasks. Timer ends, its callback is pushed on the callstack. This results in the promise getting fulfilled. As a result, a microtask is enqueued in the microtask queue to execute the fulfillment handler.

Comment: You have 3 promises: one created via constructor and the other two by calling `then` methods. Promise created via constructor is resolved when the timer callback is executed. This results in the execution of the `then` method callback inside the `fetch` function. Once that is executed, the `then` promise is resolved, leading to the execution of `then` callback in the `stuff` function. A separate microtask is enqueued in the microtask queue to execute the fulfillment handlers. Last promise `fetch.then(...)` has no fulfillment handler, so no microtask will be enqueued when it resolves.